# Notebook to write your feelings, thoughts, etc. about a person (deceased) or an organization on a special occasion

Tags: expressions, vocabulary

Notebook to write your feelings, thoughts, etc. about a person (deceased) or an organization on a special occasion:

What do you call that notebook in English?

(Testimonial notebook, memorial notebook, etc.??)

(That notebook is prepared by the person's family/the organization)

Comment: Is this a notebook by you alone, or one with entries from multiple people?

Comment: For multiple people (e.g. coming to the opening event of an organization or its anniversary)

Answer (score 2):

**Book of Remembrance**

A ‘book of remembrance’ is a special book to commemorate someone.

The French have a term for ‘visitors book’ which is ‘livre d’or’ or ‘golden book’, which is a nice idea as well.

https://www.veterans.gc.ca/eng/remembrance/memorials/books

Answer (score 1):

a **guestbook**  [OED](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/261527?redirectedFrom=guest%20book#eid)

> A book detailing the visitors or guests at a particular place or
>   event; esp. a book in which a visitors to a domestic residence, a
>   tourist attraction, etc., can leave their names, addresses, and
>   comments.

As in:

> 2003   N.Y. Times    He inscribed the words ‘never forget’ in a guest
>   book, and alighted his motorcade to return to Krakow.

and [Milwaukee Journal Sentinel](https://books.google.com/books?id=trIaAAAAIBAJ&lpg=PA56&dq=%22Funeral%20Guest%20Book%22&pg=PA56#v=onepage&q=%22Funeral%20Guest%20Book%22&f=false)

> Legacy.com powers the online obituaries of 275 newspapers nationwide,
>   including the Journal Sentinel. The company created an online version
>   of a traditional **funeral guest book.**

Comment: The word *guestbook* is not appropriate for a book concerning a deceased person.

Comment: in AmE, funeral guest books are commonly known.

Comment: A guestbook is something you might find at a bed and breakfast.

Answer (score 1):

If it's about a deceased person, it's a *book of condolence.*